# I am getting "Illegal callback invocation from native module. This callback type only permits a single invocation from native code."

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am getting an error as

> "Illegal callback invocation from native module. This callback type only permits a single invocation from native code."

I have used `react-native-image-crop-picker` to crop an image, now If I choose the cropped image I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide example of your code and how are you using the callbacks from the native code. 
But in general you can only invoke a callback from native code only once. However you can store callback and call it later as well. 
More info on callbacks in general: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#callbacks